# Trouble with get_the_category() + Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress Version 3.4.2

I am having a hard time getting the current category name to print on single.php. (outside the loop) There seems to be some sort of caching going on.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
    if the_category() == 'this posts category' {
    echo 'something';
    else do this....etc
```

I've tried several things and always end up with a cached category name. No matter which category the post belongs to.

Here is the snippet that I've been using:

```
    // outside loop
    $category = get_the_category();
    echo the_category($category[0]->cat_ID);
```

Alas, it will only print the cached category name, not the category the post is actually in. Thanks for your help. It's really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using [`wp_get_post_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories) instead. maybe something like `wp_get_post_categories($post->ID, $args)`?

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the reply Alex, but this doesn't seem to be work either.   
It still caches the array contents somehow.  

I've found that something like this works perfectly on a category page, even outside the loop:   
        
        `<?php echo single_cat_title(''); ?>`

Still can't get the contents to echo out onto single.php. :(  

Any further advice is highly appreciated. Thx.